# Why is this custom function not working on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, wordpress-theme-astra

I want to output the fields value of above meta from custom field and ads above post meta from ad inserter .
Is there any syntax error or something else. I couldn't figure out. Can anyone help me with it.

```
/**
 * Single Post Title & Meta Order
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'astra_get_single_post_title_meta' ) ) {

    function astra_get_single_post_title_meta() {

        // Single Post Title and Single Post Meta.
        do_action( 'astra_single_post_order_before' );

        ?>
        <div class="ast-single-post-order">
            <?php

            do_action( 'astra_single_post_title_before' );

            the_title(
                '<h1 class="entry-title" ' . astra_attr(
                    'article-title-blog-single',
                    array(
                        'class' => '',
                    )
                ) . '>',
                '</h1>'
            ); 

            do_action( 'astra_single_post_title_after' );

            if ( get_field( 'above_meta' ) ) {
                ?>
                <div class="astra-above-meta-single-post">
                    <?php the_field( 'above_meta' ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            do_action( 'astra_single_post_meta_before' );

            // Display ad above post meta
            if ( function_exists( 'adinserter' ) ) {
                echo adinserter( 15 );
            }

            // Display post meta
            astra_post_meta();

            do_action( 'astra_single_post_meta_after' );

            ?>
        </div>
        <?php

        do_action( 'astra_single_post_order_after' );
    }
}
```

Comment: How is  `astra_get_single_post_title_meta`  triggered as there seems no link to any hook etc here.  Do you know if it is called at all?

Comment: The astra_get_single_post_title_meta() function itself is not triggered by any hook or action within its own code. Instead, it is usually called directly by the template file used to display a single post in the Astra theme

Comment: And is it called?

Comment: Can you provide what result you have with this code ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: No i didn't see any error . And astra_get_single_post_title_meta is not called anywhere. How can i replace it

Comment: If you need to wrap it into a function (not necessary when you put it in template files), then you need to call the function by adding `astra_get_single_post_title_meta();` where you want to display the output.